# How to use DTO's decorated with NestJS swagger api in NextJS

Tags: webpack, next.js, swagger, nestjs

I found solution in - [How to use NX DTO libraries decorated with NestJS swagger api in frontend frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74939029/how-to-use-nx-dto-libraries-decorated-with-nestjs-swagger-api-in-frontend-framew)

But this solution work fine only with `next dev`.
When I call `next build` I got error like webpack loaders didn't work, while I can see they're actually called when adding `console.log()` to loader call

Here is my loader

`dto-adapter.loader.js`

```
module.exports = (source) => {
    const regex = /@(ApiProperty|RecordExists|ApiHideProperty|ApiPropertyOptional)(\(\)|\((.|\s)*?\n\t}?\)|\([^\n)]+\))/gm;
    const subst = '';
    return source.replace(regex, subst);
};
```

here is my `next.config.js`

```
const path = require('path');

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  compiler: {
    styledComponents: true,
  },
  webpack(config) {
    Array.prototype.push.apply(config.module.rules, [
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: path.resolve(__dirname, './webpack/dto-adap ter.loader.js'),
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: path.resolve(__dirname, './webpack/i18n-adapter.loader.js'),
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ])
    return config;
  },
  env: {
    RECAPTCHA_KEY: process.env.RECAPTCHA_KEY,
    API_URL: process.env.API_URL,
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

And here is error:

```
- info Creating an optimized production build
- info Compiled successfully
Failed to compile.

./src/shared-types/pagination/pagination-model.ts:1:29
Type error: Cannot find module '@nestjs/swagger' or its corresponding type declarations.
> 1 | import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger'
    |                             ^
  2 |
  3 | export class PaginationModel {
```